# thread stack size not set; while install Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

C:\Elasticsearch\bin>service install
Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"
thread stack size not set; configure via "C:\Elasticsearch\config\jvm.options" or ES_JAVA_OPTS

Answer (score 5):

Please add

**-Xss1m**

to the jvm.options file in the config folder and re-run the 'service.bat install' command.

Comment: Could you include an explanation of what the problem is and how this resolves it?

Comment: @joniba This [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/windows.html#windows-service) should help (first note in the section).